# How long does the Soyuz Instrumentation/Propulsion Module remain attached to the Descent Module during re-entry?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft

Soyuz MS-22, attached to the ISS, has [developed a leak](https://www.space.com/roscosmos-statement-soyuz-damage-leak-space-station) in an external coolant loop in the Instrumentation/Propulsion Module.  This spacecraft is needed to return the three cosmonauts who are currently onboard the ISS, either at the end of their mission or as a lifeboat in an emergency.

The Instrumentation/Propulsion Module and Orbital Module are separated from the Descent Module during re-entry.  I think I've read somewhere that return from the ISS takes three to four hours.  For how long is the Instrumentation/Propulsion module needed during the return flight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modules separate at landing minus 26 minutes, about three hours after undocking.

[image]

There is a complete timeline here: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/structure/elements/soyuz/landing_timeline.html

Comment: +1  From that link, they wait 2 hours 29 minutes until Soyuz is twelve miles from the ISS before the deorbit burn.  I wonder if they could reduce that in an emergency?  I usually deorbit my Kerbals at a few feet from their space station :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin I don't know the constraints but maybe a bigger sep burn (the one at undock + 6 minutes) followed by a sooner deorbit burn might work. But strictly a guess.